# What is the correct code for adding Sidebar functionality in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is anyone able to tell me if there is any difference between:

```
'name' => __('Main content left'),
```

and:

```
'name' => 'Main content left',
```

I have used both variations, when adding Sidebar Functionality to my WordPress Theme, and they both work.  I have checked the WordPress forums, as well as ther Codex, as it seems that the two variants are used there too.  I am just wondering if I am overlooking something or if there may be a compatibility/performance issue with one or the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the second is only a string.
the first is a function that serves for the translation of the string, it also requires a second parameter called text domain.
view this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/